# Not able to send user context IDs to Azure Application Insights

Tags: c#, azure, webforms, azure-application-insights

When I try to log the user session using the steps from this post: [Send user context IDs to enable usage experiences in Azure Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/usage-send-user-context) in webforms, the information is not available in Azure Application Insights

Repro Steps
1. Add Telemetry Inicializer

```
public class TelemetryInitializer : ITelemetryInitializer
{
    public void Initialize(ITelemetry telemetry)
    {
        var ctx = HttpContext.Current;

        // If telemetry initializer is called as part of request execution and not from some async thread
        if (ctx != null)
        {
            var requestTelemetry = ctx.GetRequestTelemetry();

            // Set the user and session ids from requestTelemetry.Context.User.Id, which is populated in Application_PostAcquireRequestState in Global.asax.cs.
            if (requestTelemetry != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(requestTelemetry.Context.User.Id) &&
                (string.IsNullOrEmpty(telemetry.Context.User.Id) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(telemetry.Context.Session.Id)))
            {
                // Set the user id on the Application Insights telemetry item.
                telemetry.Context.User.Id = requestTelemetry.Context.User.Id;

                // Set the session id on the Application Insights telemetry item.
                telemetry.Context.Session.Id = requestTelemetry.Context.User.Id;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

2. Register the Initializer at Global.asax

```
TelemetryConfiguration.Active.TelemetryInitializers.Add(new ManageTelemetryInitializer());
```

3. Fill the data at Application_PostAcquireRequestState

```
protected void Application_PostAcquireRequestState()
{
    var requestTelemetry = Context.GetRequestTelemetry();
    if (HttpContext.Current.Session != null && requestTelemetry != null && string.IsNullOrEmpty(requestTelemetry.Context.User.Id))
    {
        UserSession userSession = // GetMySession

        string userId = string.Empty;

        if (userSession != null)
        {
            userId = userSession.UserGuid.ToString("N");
        }

        requestTelemetry.Context.User.Id = userId;
        requestTelemetry.Context.Session.Id = Session.SessionID;
    }
}
```

Actual Behavior
Session data is not available in Azure Application Insights

[image]

Expected Behavior
Having the correct user session in Azure Application Insights

UPDATE:

Here's the data which I can see on the output window when I debug. Everything looks fine. I omitted some fields because of privacy.

```
{
    "name": "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Dev.fc9e8309cdd74395bf57f81d63d915d9.Message",
    "time": "2019-10-18T10:13:21.0548760Z",
    "sampleRate": 33.3333333333333,
    "iKey": "INSTRUMENTATION_KEY",
    "tags": {
        "ai.internal.sdkVersion": "sd:2.4.1-442",
        "ai.session.id": "oaluibbilrmunjxc3i1zovld",
        "ai.operation.id": "OPERATION_ID",
        "ai.location.ip": "::1",
        "ai.cloud.roleInstance": "MACHINE_NAME",
        "ai.user.id": "cef5121344374f25a325a1079473c51a",
        "ai.operation.name": "OEPRATION",
        "ai.operation.parentId": "PARENT_ID"
    },
    "data": {
        "baseType": "MessageData",
        "baseData": {
            "ver": 2,
            "message": "MESSAGE",
            "severityLevel": "Verbose",
            "properties": {
                "DeveloperMode": "true"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: During debugging session do you have `userId` and `Session.SessionID` set when the `Application_PostAcquireRequestState` is called ?

Comment: @Pietro everything is set locally

Comment: Do you see the telemetry in Application Insights. I mean everything else works as expected?

Comment: Everything works as expected, the only thing that I can't see is the Session. Is not sending the proper data. As I mentioned I fallowed microsoft guid to implement it, and even though is not working properly, the user sessions are not logged correctly.

Comment: I tried to reproduce your problem on a clean web project. The only issue I did have was the Context.Session was null. My understanding is that this is working on your side. After enabling the session, I do see `session_Id` and `user_Id` in Azure Application Insights. I am using the implementation you provided in your question as a link to ms page.

Comment: This is strange, it doesn't work for me. I will review my configuration file, maybe something is overwriting it.

Comment: Ok, let's summarize. You are receiving telemetry in Azure. `Context.Session` object is set. You do see `session_Id` but not `user_id` in Azure. Right?

Comment: @Pietro both are missing. I go to azure and there's nothing, in both Session and Users. Updated with a image of one of my AppInsights env... no data

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201036/discussion-between-pietro-and-fals).

Comment: @Fals, when debug locally from visual studio, please check the output window of visual studio to see if the userId and SessionId are added in the telemetry data.

Comment: @IvanYang the requested information was added to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mystery was solved. A combination of filters in Azure Application Insights was misleading the team from NOC. They were seeing no data because of it.

Comment: Well idk why the down votes, azure has changed how the filters work, this answer still relevant